# EmguCV ImageGrabbed Event WPF App

Tags: c#, multithreading, emgucv

I have problems with the following code

```
namespace MyApp
{    
    public partial class PhotoWindow : Window
    {
        private Capture _capture;

        public PhotoWindow ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();    
            _capture = new Capture();

            if (_capture != null)
            {
                //<Image> in XAML
                CaptureSource.Width = 150;
                CaptureSource.Height = 180;

                _capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;
                _capture.Start();                
            }

            Activated += (s, e) => _capture.Start();
            Closing += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (_capture == null) return;
                _capture.Stop();                
                _capture.Dispose();
            };
        }

        private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = _capture.RetrieveBgrFrame();                   
                CaptureSource.Source = Helper.ToBitmapSource(frame);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

when I run the application I get the exception `System.InvalidOperationException: The thread that this call can not access this object because the owner is another thread` on line `CaptureSource.Source = Helper.ToBitmapSource(frame);`

**As I can solve this?**

Answer (score 1):

It seems that ImageGrabbed event is raised from Capture's background thread and because of that your handler is running in that thread rather then the UI thread of your window.

You can use the Dispatcher to invoke code in the control's UI thread.

```
CaptureSource.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
   Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = _capture.RetrieveBgrFrame();                   
   CaptureSource.Source = Helper.ToBitmapSource(frame);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `Emgu.CV.UI.ImageBox` in the UI to display the Image<,> frame from the Capture

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = _capture.RetrieveBgrFrame();    
imageBox.Invoke(new Action(() => imageBox.Image = frame));
```